# Xcode: want multiple windows visible at launch

Tags: xcode

I'm using Xcode's interface builder to mock up the windows for a new app (which will not be written in XCode).  I don't know Xcode well at all.  I want to be able to run the project so I can see the windows and take copies of them.  But when I do that, only the MainMenu.xib's window shows.  The other windows have Visible at Launch turned on.  Is there something else I need to do?  Below is the Attributes Inspector for one of my windows.

I would be grateful for any help! :-)

[image]

Comment: add your other windows in the same `xib` as the main one? using multiple xibs is only useful for interface elements that you wish to load on demand.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but could you please tell me how to do this?  That's what I tried to do initially, but couldn't figure out how.  With Google I found that I can right-click in the Project Navigator, choose New File and then Window.  But that makes separate .xib files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably depends on your version of Xcode; for 10: If you have your `MainMenu.xib` open do `View -> Library -> Show Library` (or the corresponding toolbar button). From the library window search for "Window" and drag a new window into your `xib`. Select this new window and use the "Attributes Inspector" to check the "Visible At Launch" checkbox.

All "Visible At Launch" does is set the visible bit on the Window so that when the Nib is unarchived the window is visible. You still have to actually unarchive the Nib, either programmaticly or via a `ViewController` (which may be another option for you, but I don't know if it can be configured to automatically open).

**Word of warning here:** this is generally fine to do when you *definitely* want multiple windows at launch. Do not use this as a general solution to adding new windows to your application.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Actually all I had to do was drag the window into the xib; when I run now, it shows.  Perfect :-)